# Pure news (scollable) not working

Tags: applications, app-widgets, news-and-weather

I want to have news appear on the home screen of my tablet so I got Pure news widget. I installed it and added the widget but the widget is empty (no news shows up). I assume I need to add a feed somehow. How is this done? In the widgests settings under the tab "providers" there's a section "feedly source" and in it there's a button to "login with credentials" and if I click on it asks me to login with Google. Should I do this? I don't feel comfortable giving my Google credentials to random people and I've never heard of a "feedly" before.